# How to keep hover attributes while disabling click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So I have this list with some hover effect added through CSS. 
HTML:

```
<li><a href="#">Current Period</a>
  <ul>
        <li><a href="#">2012</a>
        <li> a href="#">2011</a> //...you get the point
```

CSS:

```css
#nav a:hover {
    background-color: #fff;
    color: #333;
}
```

When the user hovers over current period a list of children elements appear (2012, 2011... which have children of their own). My problem is that users can click on "Current Period". I have managed to remove the click by adding a class to the anchor like so:

```
<li><a href="#" class="noclick">Current Period</a> ....
```

CSS:

`.noclick {
   pointer-events: none;
   cursor: default;
}`

but this of course removes the hover feature.  I want to keep the hover effect while making the button un-clickable (I was thinking javascript, but I want a more "direct" solution). I appreciate any help :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your click handler test whether the clicked item has that class:

```
$("#nav a").click(function(e){
     if ($(e.target).hasClass("noclick"))
         return false;

     // your other code here
});
```

Note that by testing the [`target` element](http://api.jquery.com/event.target/) for the event you don't then prevent the clicks on child elements from working.

Or if the "noclick" class is not changed dynamically, i.e., those "noclick" links start out as and will always be "noclick", you could change the selector so that your click handler isn't bound to those particular elements:

```
$("#nav a").not(".noclick").click(function() { ...
```

Comment: The first piece of code makes the perfect sense and, for my purposes, fits the bill perfectly.  Thank you! I appreciate your help :)

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried?

```
$('.noclick').unbind('click');
```

or

```
$('.noclick').click(function(e){e.preventDefault();});
```

or

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);">Text</a>
```

Comment: I have tried all three of them, but the click still gets recognized by the javascript function.  Have a feeling the answer is here but I'm doing something wrong

Comment: I notice a comment on another answer where you say you have another function capturing the click. There in lies your problem.. conflicting functionality. Mind you I have no context to how your capturing that click currently, but assuming if your using jquery its likely something to the extent of `$('a').click(function(){//stuff});` which means you have to work some logic into that other function thats catching clicks on a global level to see if the link your clicking on `hasClass('noclick')` and if it does don't do what you want it to do.

Comment: Your comment, along with the one I marked as an answer, are what truly solved my problem in the easiest, less painful way. I appreciate your help, thank you :)

Comment: Well you flagged someone else, unless you meant that comment for them. But either way no problem :-D

Answer (score 1):

Just change your following line:

```
<li><a href="#" class="noclick">Current Period</a> ....
```

for this one

```
<li><a href="#" class="noclick" onclick="return false;">Current Period</a> ....
```

and change your following css:

```
.noclick { pointer-events: none; cursor: default; }
```

for this one

```
.noclick { cursor: default; }
```

that should do what you want.

Comment: I have a function on the background that still recognizes the click on the object

Answer (score 0):

You can use the noClick class to prevent the default event

```
('.noclick').on('click' , function(e) {
     e.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: This disables my other function (which checks to see if a child element was clicked)

Answer (score 0):

on .noclick class remove pointer-events

```
.noclick { cursor: default; }
```

and add js to .noclick element

```
$('.noclick').each(function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    $this.hover(function() {
        // do something...
    });
    $this.click(function() {
        return false;
    });
});
```